# Choosing $2$ groups of $5$ members and $1$ group of $2$ members from $15$ person

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> In how many ways can we choose $2$ groups of $5$ members and $1$ group of $2$ members from $15$ person?
>
> Additional info: groups are not labeled.

*Things I have done so far*: I know number of ways to choose $3$ groups of $5$ members from $15$ person is equal to $$\frac{{15 \choose 5}{10 \choose 5}}{3!}$$

However i'm not sure which is true about this question$$\frac{{15 \choose 5}{10 \choose 5}{5 \choose 2}}{3!}$$

or

$$\frac{{15 \choose 5}{10 \choose 5}{5 \choose 2}}{2!}$$

Comment: Are the groups numbered or labeled in some way?

Comment: @user84413,thanks for pointing it. no, groups are not labeled.

Comment: The last option looks good.

Comment: I agree with @barak - the last one is right I think

Comment: @user2838619, can you pls share what is the source( book/notes/site)?

Comment: @Vikram,this is from series of 62 question that my teacher gave me.

Comment: @user84413,where your answer gone?i just refreshed page to see new comments and your answer disappeared.

Comment: I think that the approach of @user84413, currently deleted, is a little safer. By choosing the group of $2$ first, it becomes clearer that one should divide by $2!$ and not by $3!$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the groups where labeled then this would just be the standard multinomial coefficient $\binom{15}{5,5,2,3}=\frac{15!}{5!\cdot5!\cdot2!\cdot3!}$ however the -groups are identical, so we are counting each case twice. The answer is then $\frac{15!}{5!\cdot5!\cdot2!\cdot3!\cdot2}=3,783,780$

Comment: which is equal to $\frac{{15 \choose 2}{13 \choose 5}{8 \choose 2}}{2!}$[computed in wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28binom%5B15%2C2%5D*binom%5B13%2C5%5D*binom%5B8%2C5%5D%29%2F2%21)

Answer (score 1):

An alternate way to get your second answer is to first choose the group of two people, which can be done in $\binom{15}{2}$ ways.  Next choose the remaining 10 people, which can be done in $\binom{13}{10}$ ways.  Now take one of these 10 people, and choose their 4 partners, which can be done in $\binom{9}{4}$ ways.

This gives $\binom{15}{2}\binom{13}{10}\binom{9}{4}$ possibilities.

Comment: This is identical to OP's last proposed option (just use "\frac" in your formula).

Comment: @ barak manos You're right; my original answer was equivalent to the OP's second answer, even though it looked different.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is: $\frac{{15 \choose 5} {10 \choose 5} {5 \choose 2} {3 \choose 3}}{2!}$

The reason for 2! in the denominator is, that here are 2 groups, which have the same number of group members (5).

For example: $1,2,3,4,5 - 6,7,8,9,10$ is the same like $6,7,8,9,10-1,2,3,4,5$